# how does flyway lock a postgres schema?

Tags: flyway

I am using Flyway with Postgres and I have noticed that if I have my tomcat server running, and I try to execute a `DROP SCHEMA foo` it does not work until tomcat shuts down. I am assuming that flyway has some mechanism to block modifications to the schema after it runs. How is the blocking of other clients modifying the schema accomplished in flyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Flyway doesn't lock the schema.**

When it starts applying a migration, it begins a transaction. It then acquires a lock on the metadata table using `SELECT * FROM metadatatable FOR UPDATE`. This lock is released automatically after the migration completes when the transaction is commited or rolled back.

Comment: Looking at the src code today, it attempts a pg_try_advisory_lock, with only a 5 second timeout: 
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/postgresql/PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.java